How to create TV 4k resolution emulator in Android Studio?
I am trying to create a 4K emulator in Android Studio like in the screenshot below

According to the configuration displayed, the resolution should be 3840x2160 and the density xxxhdpi which is 640, however, I have an app where I try to get resolution and density and present it on the screen.

The code is:
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                val screenDensity: Float = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat()

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "screenDensity: $screenDensity"
                )

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "height: ${LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels}"
                )

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "width: ${LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels}"
                )
            }

The question is - what am I missing here - why 4k emulator has been created, but, it has a completely different configuration?
UPD
Emulator runs on UpsideDownCake API 34


What OS version are you running? It looks like 4K Android TV support began in Android 12.

@CommonsWare it is UpsideDownCake API 34 )(also added screenshot in the question)

If it is an emulator, your system may not be running in 4k (I am only guessing this could be the reason)

@NishantJalan, weird, I am using macbook pro m1, I believe this laptop is supposed to support 4K
